# How to conditionally bypass request interceptor in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm having trouble bypassing my auth interceptor:

request: function (config) {

```
    if (config.headers["NoAuth2"] !== null) return config;

    config.headers = config.headers || {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
    } else {
        var authService = $injector.get('authService');
        authService.logOut();
        $location.path('/login');
    }

    return config;
}
```

Ideally, when the headers have NoAuth2 present in it's collection, I'd like to bypass adding the token and just return the config via something like:

```
$http.post(config.url + "pubrequest", request, { headers : {NoAuth2 : 1}})
```

From my controller.

However, I can't seem to get it to work despite several SOE examples on it, any ideas?

Comment: I dont see anything wrong. It's possible your if statement is failing but we have no way of testing that.

Comment: @Ronnie it seems that when check config from debug in FF, there's only an accept header for json and text.  Am I setting the header correctly on the post?